# How do I disable "scheduled scan" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Occasionally some sort of scheduled scan starts in Windows 7 on my computer (indicated by the text "scheduled scan" in the action center triangular flag in the taskbar). I cannot determine what application it is but it monopolizes the disk, slowing the computer to a crawl. How can I disable it?

Comment: It will probably be the anti-virus software. Which AV software do you have installed? Are you on a corporate network?

Answer (score 1):

You should check Task Scheduler first. Go to Control Panel -> Task Scheduler and check if there is some tasks defined.

By default Disk Defragmenter (can be found from Control Panel) is scheduled to run regularly. Unfortunately it do have separate scheduling (inside Disk Defragmenter there is "Configure Schedule" button).

In addition to that most of antivirus softwares are running full scans regularly, in addition to realtime scanning.

Some spyware scanners are also running scheduled tasks outside of Task Scheduler, for example Spybot Search&Destroy and AdAware.

When program starts, you can go to Resource Monitor (Task Manager -> Performance tab -> Resource monitor) and to disk tab. From there you can easily see what tasks are using hard disk.

Comment: The disk tab in  resource monitor  doesn't list any process and total disk usages less than 1 KB/sec in burst about every one second with a queue length of 10. Average CPU usage for the "System" process is around 25.

Comment: My guess is that your disk or motherboard is broken. Queue should be 0 with so slow usage. Unless you are using something exotic, for example network disk as a boot device, and you are having network problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Go to Task Scheduler
2. In the left menu go to Task Scheduler Library → Microsoft → Windows Defender
3. There is one task, MP Scheduled Scan. Right-click and Disable it.

That's it!

Answer (score -1):

Nemanjais correct:
Scheduled tasks are buried in
Control Panels -> Administrator Tools -> Task scheduler -> Microsoft 
BUT
The Scheduled scan is Windows Defender -> Tools -> Automatic Scanning
-> Scan my computer -> Frequency -> Daily.

OMG... Now I am going to turn it off, and disable it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.